# Validation of DateTime Format

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to validate datetime format which user can provide. Here is the sample code ...

```
 DateTime tempDateTime;
 string _userFormat = "aa";

 string tempDateTime2 = DateTime.Now.ToString(_userFormat);
 bool b = DateTime.TryParseExact(tempDateTime2, _userFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDateTime);

 Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", tempDateTime, b);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

This returns true (value of b) and valid dateTime (tempDateTime). I was in impression that this will return false because the _userFormat is not valid format. So is there any other way or am i missing something.

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think that `aa` isn't a valid format string? It doesn't convey any information, but it's not actually invalid. You could always check whether the reparsed value bore any relation to the original value... You'd need to decide how much information needs to be retained - the year/month/day? The time to the minute? To the second?

Comment: If you look at the value of `tempDateTime2` in the debugger you'll see why it succeeds.

Comment: @DStanley: Yup - I edited my comment accordingly about a minute ago :)

Comment: Note that even "valid" format strings can lose information from the original data/time - You can have "valid" strings that extract just the date, time, hour, year, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `ToString()` with the format `aa`, which does not represent a valid custom format code, the code it treated as a string literal and you get the string value `aa` back.

When you then try to *parse* the "date" using the same format specifier, it sees that the format of the source string matches the format specifier, so it parses it without error.  Since neither the source nor format code specifies any viable information about the data/time, a "default" value of `DateTime.Now.Date` is used.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

> If format defines a time with no date element and the parse operation succeeds, the resulting DateTime value has a date of `DateTime.Now.Date`.